# Android 12 notification/widget PendingIntents show other activity after closing

Tags: android

After updating my device to android 12, activities that I start from notifications or widgets using a PendingIntent will show another activity that was started before (like the launcher activity) after closing that activity.

I've tried using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the activity launch mode.

```
 android:launchMode=["standard" | "singleTop" |
                          "singleTask" | "singleInstance" | "singleInstancePerTask"]
```

In your case, you will need to set it to single instance to prevent that problem.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

You can check more about setting up activites here ->  [element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` on the activity in AndroidManifest.xml seems to solve the issue